# How to make autofac KeyFilter works in asp.net-core web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

Cannot use KeyFilter attribute to resolve registered type in asp.net core web api 2.2

I wanna use Autofac to resolve different instance of a type. I registered type in Startup.ConfigureServices by using RegisterType().Keyed and RegisterType().Named.

I can use IContainer.ResolveKeyed to resolve instance, but can't use KeyFilter to resolve instance in constructor

### Startup

```
   public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public static IContainer Container { get; private set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddControllersAsServices();

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.Populate(services);

            builder.RegisterType<Foobar>().UsingConstructor(typeof(string)).WithParameter("name", "Eric").Named<Foobar>("Eric").SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterType<Foobar>().UsingConstructor(typeof(string)).WithParameter("name", "Fred").Keyed<Foobar>("Fred").SingleInstance();

            Container = builder.Build();

            var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(Container);
            return serviceProvider;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

### ValuesController

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly Foobar fb1;
        private readonly Foobar fb2;

        public ValuesController([KeyFilter("Eric")]Foobar fbEric, [KeyFilter("Fred")]Foobar fbFred)
        {
            // KeyFilter not work
            fb1 = fbEric;
            fb2 = fbFred;
            
            // Container.ResolvedKeyed work
            fb1 = Startup.Container.ResolveKeyed<Foobar>("Eric");
            fb2 = Startup.Container.ResolveNamed<Foobar>("Fred");
        }
        
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { fb1.Say(), fb2.Say() };
        }
    }
```

Use KeyFilter will throw below exceptions:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating Autofac.MI.WebApi.Controllers.ValuesController. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Autofac.MI.WebApi.Controllers.ValuesController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Autofac.MI.ClassLib.Foobar fbEric' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Autofac.MI.ClassLib.Foobar, Autofac.MI.ClassLib.Foobar)'.
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ReflectionActivator.cs:line 160
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Activators\Reflection\ReflectionActivator.cs:line 120
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& decoratorTarget) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 117
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& decoratorTarget) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 135
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\InstanceLookup.cs:line 83
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 131
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\Core\Resolving\ResolveOperation.cs:line 84
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 1041
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in C:\projects\autofac\src\Autofac\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 871
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ServiceBasedControllerActivator.Create(ControllerContext actionContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: If you [read the docs on those attributes](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html#ensure-the-container-uses-your-attributes) then you know you have to have the controllers all registered using `WithAttributeFiltering()` to opt into that behavior. Where is that code?

Comment: Thanks @Travis Illig, calling WithAttributeFiltering() is the right way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `KeyFilter`, you need to register the service with `WithAttributeFiltering`.

For `AddControllersAsServices`, it only register the service to service collection, but it did not register with `WithAttributeFiltering`.

Try code below:

```
services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Populate(services);
builder.RegisterType<Foobar>().UsingConstructor(typeof(string)).WithParameter("name", "Eric").Named<Foobar>("Eric").SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<Foobar>().UsingConstructor(typeof(string)).WithParameter("name", "Fred").Keyed<Foobar>("Fred").SingleInstance();
var controllers = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(ControllerBase)).ToArray(); // for api controller
//var controllers = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Controller)).ToArray(); // for mvc controller
builder.RegisterTypes(controllers).WithAttributeFiltering();

Container = builder.Build();
```

Comment: How doing like this for .NET 6?