# Configure two instance of same type for different constructors in autofac

Tags: automapper, .net-6.0, autofac

I'm developing an ASP.NET project using .NET 6, Autofac for dependency injection, and AutoMapper for object mapping. In my project, I have two services, A and B, each of which requires its own AutoMapper configuration.
I have configured AutoMapper in my **`Startup.cs`** for service A, using the following code:

```
var mappingConfigA = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
{
    config.AddProfile(new AMappingProfile());
});

IMapper mapperA = mappingConfigA.CreateMapper();

builder.RegisterInstance(mapperA).As<IMapper>().SingleInstance();
```

Now, I need to configure a separate **`IMapper`** for service B using **`autofac.json`** while keeping service A's configuration intact. I want to avoid using key filtering and instead use **`autofac.json`** to define the **`IMapper`** for service B.

I need help understanding how to correctly configure a separate AutoMapper profile for service B using **`autofac.json`** and ensure that it uses its own mapper configuration. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html#autofac

Comment: I want to use **`autofac.json`** @LucianBargaoanu

Comment: related to [Autofac Configuration for constructor with KeyFilter attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43636554/1539100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use two types of implementation for single interface, based on specific condition in wiring, and want to use configuration file only. you have to use `key` attribute in configuration file and add controller as service.

I add some example in https://github.com/soroshsabz/TestSolution

but for further explanation I add this example below

My assumption is `Controllers` like below (Using `KeyFilter`)

```
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,
                      [KeyFilter(nameof(DummyA))]IDummyModel dummyModel)
{
      _logger = logger;
      _dummyModel = dummyModel;
}
```

First of all, I write a simple `Startup.cs` for specify conditions of dependency loading, and write `ConfigureServices` and `ConfigureContainer` like below

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
        }

        public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("autofac.json");
            var autoFacConfigurationModule = new ConfigurationModule(configurationBuilder.Build());

            builder.RegisterModule(autoFacConfigurationModule);

            //var controllers = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(ControllerBase)).ToArray(); // for api controller
            var controllers = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(Controller)).ToArray(); // for mvc controller
            builder.RegisterTypes(controllers).WithAttributeFiltering();
        }
```

Then I write some configuration like below

```json
{
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "AutofacHandyMVCTest.Models.DummyA, AutofacHandyMVCTest",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "AutofacHandyMVCTest.Models.IDummyModel, AutofacHandyMVCTest",
          "key": "DummyA"
        }
      ],
      "instanceScope": "per-lifetime-scope"
    }
  ]
}
```

as you can see, if I want to load `DummyA` I just need to set key to `DummyA` in configuration file.

---

**References:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43646325/1539100
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57550018/1539100
- [The Subtle Perils of Controller Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://www.strathweb.com/2016/03/the-subtle-perils-of-controller-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-core-mvc/)
- [autofac documentation](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services)